# How to share transparent PNG file using intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I'm using this code for sharing generated Bitmap file:

```
String pathofBmp = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), captured,"title", null);
Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);
Intent emailIntent1 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
emailIntent1.setType("image/png");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent1, "Share image using"));
```

Everything is OK, But shared photo loses its transparent background. So my question is that: How can I share the bitmap file using Intent with transparent background.
Any Idea?

**Update:**
I'm using this way to take screen shot:

```
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
     Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
        view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
         view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: imho it should work this way. What makes you believe that you loose the transparency?

Comment: @ligi I tested the result, and shared image has a black background.

Comment: Does the image saved to disk actually have transparency, or is it being saved to disk with a background? My bet is that the problem is occurring when you save it, not when you share it.

Comment: @Tanis.7x I've updated my question. I showed how to take screenshot.

Comment: When you are taking the screenshot, I suspect it's using non-transparent bitmap and hence you save the file without transparency to start with.

Comment: @AleksG When I set result in a image view, it's good, my problem is when sharing the image.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi - i'm having the same problem. Were you able to solve this?